# Application structure in backbone and requirejs app

Tags: backbone.js, require, backbone-routing

I am developing a app using backbone and requirejs. I have structured the app like this:

1. A main index.html file having `<script data-main="app.js" src="vendor-libraries/require.js"></script>`
2. In app.js i do like this:

   ```
   require.config({

       paths:{
   //all paths here
   },

   shim: {
       // all shims here
       },
       }
    });

        require(['jquery',
    'Backbone',
    'views/master',
    'views/dashboard',
    //all other views are loaded as dependencies here...

    ],function($,Backbone,masterView,dashboardView, .....){

        var Router=Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes:{
                 "":"loadDashboard",
                 "home":"loadDashboard",
                 //all routes paths go here
               },

           initialize:function(){
           this.children={
           dashboardView: new dashboardView(),
           //all views initialized as the dashboard view
           }
       },

       loadDashboard: function(){
       this.children.dashboardView.render();
       },

       //functions for all routes here...

       });

   var router = new Router();
   var view=new masterView();
   Backbone.history.start();
   ```

   });
3. In the master view i just navigate on the click of the buttons to respective views.

Now, I am just beginning with this app and my fear is that, following the above work flow can result in loading of ALL the view files at once. And in all the views, i have several templates getting loaded. So will i end up with every bit of html loaded before page render? If yes, what should be modified in the above approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if have too many things to be loaded on your page you could just require your views files as they are needed.

For example let's say you will have a Userlist View, it could be loaded in this way from your router:

```
routes: {
    ...
    'userslist' : 'loadUsersList'
}

loadUsersList: function() {

    require('views/userslist',function(UserListView) {

        UserListView.render();
    });

}
```

Comment: so will it make a request to load this view everytime a user navigates to this route?

Comment: Yes it will request the view file only when the browser hit the route, anyway after the first time the file is already loaded and so it will not be downloaded again...

Comment: and this is managed by requirejs to not to download the file again? and is the whole flow of app i mentioned is correct?

Comment: Yep, you can check it with the Network table of Chrome's developer tools, if you hit the route back the file will not be requested again.

Comment: ok. another concern is that, when i hit the route again, the views will get re-rendered. so all the events etc. will be redundantly binded? shouldn't there be something to remove previous view before generating a new one? if yes, how do i go with this in this case?

Comment: Yes you're right, this is likely to occour, it's a thing called "zombie-views". There are multiple ways to avoid it.

I suggest you to read this [blog post](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/) by Derick Bailey that explain the problem and how to avoid it.

Anyway there are library built on top of Backbone, like [Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/) that facilitate creating a complex app with Backbone a lot. Marionette also has a built-in memory manager that take care of zombie-views.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26092/discussion-between-benerd-and-ingro)